# Referencing the Nested Object from Parent Object

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am not sure why I am not able to make a reference to the child object properties from parent. Here is the relationship:

```
@class Vegetable;

@interface MyVegetableGarden : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval datecreated;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval datemodified;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL active;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Vegetable *vegetable;

@end
```

And here is the Vegetable class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class VegetableCategory;

@interface Vegetable : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * about;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL active;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval dateCreated;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval dateModified;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * imageURL;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) VegetableCategory *vegetableCategory;

@end
```

Now, I am trying to access the name property of the Vegetable class using the following code:

```
MyVegetableGarden *v = [[MyVegetableGarden alloc] init];

v.vegetable.name   // For some reason the compiler says that name property is not found
```

Comment: Are you importing Vegetable and MyVegetableGarden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've #imported Vegetable.h in the file where you access the name property

Comment: Thanks Chris! That was the problem! I will accept your answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can create an `NSManagedObject` like that :S

The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html) state

> If you instantiate a managed object directly, you must call the designated initializer (`initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`).

Also see

> Important:  This method is the designated initializer for NSManagedObject. You must not initialize a managed object simply by sending it init.